# why tomcat 7 cannot load the gcm-server.jar from WEB-INF/lib?

Tags: web-applications, servlets, tomcat7

I am working on a simple Servlet which is used to send push notification to Android devices. Here is the code portion which sends the message:

```
Sender sender = new Sender(API_KEY);
ArrayList<String> devicesList = new ArrayList<String>();
devicesList.add(regID1);
devicesList.add(regID2);
devicesList.add(regID3);

Message message = new Message.Builder()
.collapseKey("1")
.timeToLive(3)
.delayWhileIdle(true)
.addData("message",
        "Hello!!!")
.build();

MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, devicesList, 1);
sender.send(message, devicesList, 1);
```

There's nothing wrong at the compile time but when I run the servlet on my localhost an exception was threw - a ClassNotFound exception:

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
at servlet.PostServlet.doGet(PostServlet.java:48)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I guess that this happens because tomcat could not load the classes in the gcm-server.jar. However, I have already put it in the WEB-INF/lib and set the classpath. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this library to WEB-INF/lib

http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/downloads/detail?name=json-simple-1.1.1.jar